# How to Setup Multiple Filters in React/React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have two components: LeagueSelect and TeamSelect. These are filters that when used show specific content.
[image]

These are my goals:

1. Use each filter to make an api request to the endpoint that I have setup through setting query parameters.
2. If a league is unselected, make the corresponding teams for that league not able to be selected.

My question is, at a high level, how would you go about doing this 'the react way'?